# Is "Windows x64 Shell Extension dispatch for Context Menus" necessary?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, shell-extensions

My new Win7 X64 laptop takes forever to popup the context menu for a file or folder.

Using ShellExView, I narrowed it down to "Windows x64 Shell Extension dispatch for Context Menus" in ccshelxbx64.dll. Disabling this shell extension removes the lag.

Now: is this shell extension strictly necessary and what do I miss when I disable it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[After 5s of google](http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/ccshelxbx64-dll/12081773) you would know that this DLL belongs to an IBM tool. You must decide if you need this or not.

Comment: Your link tells me that this is probably what should give clearcase context menus (it is a corporate laptop). This gives me a much better feeling that I can disable this particular shell extension. Thanks.